# Hide action when Project Nature is/not added

Tags: eclipse-plugin

New to Eclipse Plugin dev.  We are developing a custom plugin that has a builder in it on MyEclipse 10, which I believe is Eclipse Indigo.

Anyway, I used the sample code generated by the Builder wizard, modified it, and got it working.  Now I am trying to get the "Toggle Nature" action to be more of an "Add Nature" or "Remove Nature", depending on if the nature if present or not.

I have the following in the plugin.xml (I have changed some of the names to protect the innocent):

```
<extension
       point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
    <objectContribution
          adaptable="true"
          id="Sample_Eclipse_Plugin.contribution1"
          nameFilter="*"
          objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">

          <menu
                label="Sample"
                id="mainSampleMenu"
                menubarPath="additions">
             <separator
                   name="group1">
             </separator>
          </menu>
          <action
                class="com.sample.eclipse.builder.AddSampleNatureAction"
                enablesFor="+"
                id="Sample_Eclipse_Plugin.addNatureAction"
                label="Add Sample Project Nature"
                menubarPath="mainSampleMenu/group1">
             <enabledWhen>
                <with variable="selection">
                   <iterate ifEmpty="false" operator="or">
                         <with variable="projectNature">
                            <not>
                               <equals value="Sample_Eclipse_Plugin.sampleNature"/>
                            </not>
                         </with>
                   </iterate>
                </with>
             </enabledWhen>
          </action>
          <action
                class="com.sample.eclipse.builder.RemoveSampleNatureAction"
                enablesFor="+"
                id="Sample_Eclipse_Plugin.removeNatureAction"
                label="Remove Sample Project Nature"
                menubarPath="mainSampleMenu/group1">
             <enabledWhen>
                <with variable="selection">
                   <iterate ifEmpty="false" operator="or">
                         <with variable="projectNature">
                            <equals value="Sample_Eclipse_Plugin.sampleNature"/>
                         </with>
                   </iterate>
                </with>
             </enabledWhen>
          </action>
    </objectContribution>
 </extension>
```

The pop-up menu shows perfectly, however I still get both the Add and Remove options.  All of this is based on the sample code Eclipse generated, and me piecing together stuff I found online through Google searches.  I am sure I am doing something really dumb due to lack of knowledge, but any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add Sample Project Nature**

```
<enabledWhen>
   <with variable="selection">
      <iterate ifEmpty="true" operator="and">
         <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
            <not>
               <test
                     property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                     value="Sample_Eclipse_Plugin.sampleNature" />
            </not>
         </adapt>
      </iterate>
   </with>
</enableWhen>
```

It tests that all (`operator="and"`) natures are not sampleNature.
If the selected project has no nature, sampleNature can (`ifEmpty="true"`) be added.

**Remove Sample Project Nature**

```
<enabledWhen>
   <with variable="selection">
      <iterate ifEmpty="false" operator="or">
         <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
            <test
                  property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                  value="Sample_Eclipse_Plugin.sampleNature" />
         </adapt>
      </iterate>
   </with>
</enableWhen>
```

It tests that one of (`operator="or"`) natures is sampleNature.
If the selected project has no nature, sampleNature cannot (`ifEmpty="false"`) be removed.

I have tested a similar code in Eclipse 4.3.1 (Kepler).

Comment: It only took 9 months, but better late than never :)